# Is it X11 programming that I have to study to create a program that locks a screen?

Tags: qt, qt4, gtk, x11

I want to create a program that locks a screen on a modern linux distribution similar to xlock. Shall I study x11 or build on projects that have been done before. If so which ones. I'm looking for keywords to aid me in my research.

Comment: @Evgeni lock the screen. Just like win + L does to windows. But I want to unlock the screen using my own authentication mechanism.

Comment: omg, sorry, misread. i feel stupid now :-(

Answer (score 2):

You should download and look at the source code of GNOME's and KDE's screen locker applications. If they use Xlib directly, then it likely can't be avoided.

You can download KDE's screen locker application using

```
sudo apt-get source kscreenlocker
```

Comment: Is there a framework on top of Xlib that makes this stuff easier to develop?

Comment: Yes, even 2 - KDE and GNOME. Also, see my edit - you can download kscreenlocker using `sudo apt-get source kscreenlocker`

Comment: Great @satuon. So is it different programming I have to do for the tow desktop environments or is there a common technology to write for both?

Comment: Actually, a gnome app will work on kde, and a kde app will work on gnome, at least in ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, "toolkits" like GTK+ & Qt are the frameworks on top of X that make applications easier to develop.  Writing programs that call Xlib directly is discouraged as you end up reimplementing much of what the toolkits provide.